# Did you find any better feature in IE 8 Developer than firebug?

Tags: css, xhtml, firebug, ie-developer-tools

Does IE 8 Developer toolbar have something better than firebug ? How to use IE 8 Developer toolbar in a way like we use firebug in firefox.? Is there any good tutorial on "how to take good use of  IE 8 Developer toolbar"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for something that mimics firebug in IE (your question is unclear), then there is [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).  If you're looking for a resource for learning about the IE8 Developer Toolbar there is [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565626%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and a number of other articles available via simple searches.

**edit**: got a more up-to-date link for the Dev Toolbar article

Comment: no "IE8 Developer Toolbar" is far better than "Firebug Lite". and 15 second's article is not for "IE8 Developer Toolbar".

Comment: It's for the earlier beta of the IE Developer Toolbar, so I updated the link to a better one.  The point remains your question is unclear - why are you asking about Firebug if you like the Developer Toolbar better?  How do you know it's better than Firebug if you need instructional resources about it?

Answer (score 1):

While the IE Developer's ToolBar, which was an addon for IE<8 and has been integrated into IE>8, is tightly integrated into IE and has it's own unique benefits for debugging IE specific issues, I find Firebug to be more conducive to general debugging scenarios.

That is my take on the first of your THREE questions ;-)

I will leave the rest to others.